# Can't manage with lxml to have both pretty printing and not turning xml elements to self-closing elements

Tags: python, lxml, pretty-print

I'm currently facing a dilemma.

This code below doesn't print my XML properly :

```py
import lxml.etree

xml_tree = lxml.etree.parse("myFile.xml")
root = xml_tree.getroot()

for fruit in root:
    if fruit.tag == "apple":
        for apple in fruit:
            if apple.tag == "McIntosh":
                fruit.remove(apple)

tree = lxml.etree.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("output.xml", pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8")
```

Here is my XML input file :

```xml
<fruits>
  <apple>
    <McIntosh/>
  </apple>
</fruits>
```

And here is my (ugly) output XML file. the indentation is not correct :

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<fruits>
  <apple>
    </apple>
</fruits>
```

I read somewhere that to get the pretty printing actually work, I had to use a `lxml.etree.XMLParser` with the `remove_blank_text=True` option like this :

```py
xml_parser = lxml.etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
xml_tree = lxml.etree.parse("myFile.xml", xml_parser)
```

It works to actually activate the pretty printing but on the other hand my empty XML elements are now turned into self-closing elements :

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<fruits>
  <apple/>
</fruits>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this side effect of lxml pretty printing ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77331645/pretty-printing-is-failing-with-lxml-when-i-add-an-element-to-an-empty-element/77331694?noredirect=1#comment136330882_77331694) you just asked use the `indent` function to fix your pretty print.

Regarding creating non self-closing tags, this happens because the text property is set to None, just set it to an empty string as answered [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41890892/19117747).

Comment: Thx for the tip !
Unfortunately, this technique sticks the start tag and the end tag together on the same line while I need the start tag and the end tag to be indented on 2 different lines. I already have a python function I made to pretty print XML document but I wanted to use the already defined tools from lxml to have something more reliable. Seems I will have to stick to my own code.